# MySQL not starting in MAMP PRO

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mamp

Right, so i've been playing with MAMP and use it to mess around with wordpress plugins and themes. However, I've been forced to keep MAMP running at all times because the moment I restart the server (after the first install of MAMP), mySql doesnt start. It works immediately after reinstalling MAMP, but anytime I stop it, it simply gives me an error. The exact error log is:

> 150812 10:31:33 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases
>   from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql 150812
>   10:31:33 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file
>   system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/
>   is case insensitive 150812 10:31:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is
>   disabled. /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' 
>   doesn't exist 150812 10:31:33 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin
>   table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it. 150812 10:31:33 InnoDB: 
>   The InnoDB memory heap is disabled 150812 10:31:33 InnoDB: Mutexes
>   and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 150812 10:31:33 InnoDB:
>   Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3 150812 10:31:33 InnoDB: Initializing 
>   buffer pool, size = 128.0M 150812 10:31:33 InnoDB: Completed
>   initialization of buffer pool 150812 10:31:33 InnoDB: highest
>   supported file format is Barracuda. 150812 10:31:33  InnoDB: Waiting
>   for the background threads to start 150812 10:31:34 InnoDB: 5.5.42
>   started; log sequence number 346953327 150812 10:31:34 [ERROR] Fatal
>   error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host'
>   doesn't exist 150812 10:31:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

I've literally tried everything from killing all mysql processes, to changing port numbers, to restarting both MAMP and the Computer... Nothing seems to work. I even changed the file permission of host.frm to allow all users read&write access.

I have spent hours and hours looking to no avail :( Any suggestions would be HUGELY appreciated!

Thank you!

Shayne

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall it and try to install different version ? @Shayne Thomas

Comment: Well, thats the thing. It works fine when I reinstall MAMP. The issue arrises when I then first close the program, and then come to start it again. So for a while, I reinstalled MAMP, left it running for days and days while I worked, and then I had to turn off my computer - which obviously closed the program, causing the above problem :( Im installing the latest version of MAMP. You recon I should try an older version?

Comment: Yep, that might cause from the version you are using, MAMP has several problem with "Yosemite OS" if you are using it be careful. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll give it a go and post my results when I can.

Comment: Oh I did forget to add that I had the exact same issue when using ampps too... :(

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: Im using OS X 10.10.3...

Comment: Hi again, Unfortunately a different version of MAMP Pro (used version 3.0) doesn't resolve the issue. :(

Comment: mate were u able to fix that?

Comment: Hey dude, If i remember correctly, I did try reinstalling MAMP and i think that didn't even work :( But, I did reformat my computer a week or so later (guessing that may not be an option for you), and it worked when I installed it on a clean computer.@zok